# Was there ever a photo that made people cry?

Tags: history, mood, emotion

With video, it's pretty easy to evoke emotions. I've seen movies, short clips, music video, animations etc that gets so emotional it would make people cry. Is there something similar with photography? I guess it's exponentially more difficult with such one frame?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course they can. They can change the world. Here's one that did both:

[image: not much more to say]

Comment: I can see this making softhearted people emotional, but how did it change the world? Seems there is a story to that.

Comment: It was one of a few key images that turned the majority of the voting public in the U.S. against the war in Vietnam on the late 1960s. This in turn changed the course of the *Cold War* between the U.S. and the Soviet Union.

Comment: This image won't necessarily make everyone cry, but if it _doesn't_ make you emotional in some way (no matter your political views!), I think it's time for some introspection on what exactly "softhearted" means.

Comment: +1 A quick look at the [world press photo award archives](http://archive.worldpressphoto.org/years) certainly provides a wealth of imagery, much of which is highly emotional.  It is perhaps easier to evoke emotions in moving images than static ones but emotional connections that are easily made are equally easily broken.

Comment: accompanied with the story, it certainly helps. alone it just looks like some soldiers walking casually down a road with something burning in the background, escorting some seemingly set-up kids, who despite the casual soldiers look like they are running and screaming. But there are also a lot of political spin and money made from this picture which takes away from the emotional impact. I dont see why anyone would change their opinion on war from it - what did they think a war was like before seeing this...there are much more gruesome pics out there from warzones.

Comment: the the question is of it can be emotional without being told the story (like moving pictures can)?

Comment: Looking at a lot of the Pulitzer prize winning photos can evoke strong emotions from many people, more so if the story surrounding them is well known or explained in detail

Comment: This one makes me cry: http://blog.gettyimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/Arlington-National-Cemetery-Memorial-Day-John-Moore-Getty-Images-74345339-e1337978526107.jpg

Comment: @MichaelNielsen How many news photos do you remember instantly 3+ decades on? If somebody described a 30+ year old photo to people, how many people would know the picture they were referring to after a few sentences? This is one such. Most adults who saw that photo at the time had a fair enough idea of what it was about. A SMALL amount of accompanying text would not have hurt. Or a banner headline. ".... NAPALM ..." probably featured. | FWIW the wider shots that accompanied this sequence - but which I only saw decades later on - made it look and feel quite different.

Comment: A few of mine made me cry on occasions subsequently - and some still produce a substantial reaction long afterwards. It's harder to make that more universal, but by no means unknown. One of mine that gets to me in a good sort of way is of a marching pipe band in full array with a crowd of people strung out behind. It happens to evoke  a sense of national pride, memories of was losses long ago, patriotism, solidarity, patriotism and a bit more. To me, anyway :-). | "We shall remember them".

Comment: .... Here 'tis - no great reaction now - some years old. Few others would be so moved :-). http://bit.ly/WeShallRememberThem  [Happens to be taken on our nations "most holy day" on the way to an "Anzac Day" celebration. Note representatives of all armed services behind pipers and then supporting gaggle of 'ordinary folk'.

Comment: I believe that the longer something lasts beyond one frame the **impact of immediacy is lost**, the longer the exposition lasts you can get a **more nuanced feel but also one far less striking**.  Note that when people talk about a great movie they quickly break it down to many wonderful scenes and then to one brilliant frame.  PS: may god bless pipers of all nations, @RussellMcMahon =)

Comment: [**ARBEIT MACHT FREI**](https://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfa1/t31.0-8/p640x640/321707_251904818216354_1576070848_o.jpg) - more like pointless, decades too late, blind fury

Comment: Actually, that arbeit macht frei gave me shivers. But thats because I know all that is behind it. The pipers dont give me an emotional reaction, other than I think it is great that people keep up traditions like that, even if it looks funny. I listen to some good deaht metal bands with bagpipes, too.

Answer (score 3):

I think the advantage that you're seeing is that video has the opportunity to setup the context for the viewer that will later be used to evoke emotion that photos cannot do. For example, had I seen a single frame from the ending of the movie The Blind Side where he's being drafted I wouldn't care in the slightest, but after having seen the movie I knew the context and had a better idea of what it meant; it was more moving (figuratively) because of the backstory, not because that particular scene was moving (literally) and not frozen. If you know your audience it can be easier (in motion or stills) to evoke emotion from them.

I would imagine there are many crime scene photos that make the surviving families cry, many wedding photos that make widows/widowers, etc. I think that even if the photos were videos instead the impact would be the same because the context is the same.

Answer (score 2):

This one most likely did:

[image]

I agree with @tenmiles that it's all about context. What makes people emotional are stories, and it's hard for a single frame to tell enough of a story. But it's possible.

Comment: I think you've nailed it re: stories.